# R character substring

Tags: r, timestamp, substring

I have a folder full of files that are named something like "CH7Data_20130401T130110.csv", "CH7Data_20130401T130610.csv" etc.

I got a list of all files in that folder using below command

```
filenames=list.files(path = "//folder location", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
```

Now I would like to get a character array, which contains timestamps from all file names. From each file name i want to extract text between _ and .
what is the most efficient way to do that? I started using substring and unlist commands but they seem inefficient as I have to use multiple of them.

and finally how can i covert these time stamp vector into a vector of actual times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filenames <- c("CH7Data_20130401T130110.csv", "CH7Data_20130401T130610.csv")
timestamps <- gsub(".*_([^.]+).*", "\\1", filenames)
## [1] "20130401T130110" "20130401T130610"
as.POSIXlt(timestamps, format = "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
## [1] "2013-04-01 13:01:10 PDT" "2013-04-01 13:06:10 PDT"
```

Comment: I am going to sort the array/vector of time values in Descending order. Any quick way to subtract 2nd element from 1st, 3rd from 2nd etc? I want to find out average time difference between each file

Comment: @user2543622 see `?diff`